# Find all method calls where any of the parameters has a known name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

What I want to do is find any instances of a method call (where the method name is unknown) where any of that methods parameters has a name of X, where X is a parameter I'm interested in (of any type). The method may be either in my own code, or part of the framework or another library.

Is there a way to do this from within VS itself?

Comment: Do you know all the assemblies you want to look through? If so, it's easy enough via reflection - which you could build into VS if you wanted, of course.

Comment: Are you talking about in code or in the IDE?

Comment: Have you had a look at the 'View Call Hierarchy' in VS? Also, you know that parameter names can be anything when calling a method as long as the types are the same as the method requiring the parameters.

Comment: @Sayse, in the IDE. Not at runtime.

Comment: @nocturns2 how does that help me if I don't know what the method is to start with? It shows the calls from or to a given starting point - but I don't know what the method in question is.

Comment: @JonSkeet I could use reflection to find all methods who have any parameter of a given name, but finding only the ones that I actually call anywhere in my code is a different issue.

Comment: I've never had to deal with your requirements in the past. So the first place I looked was where I directed you. Beyond that I would look at the 'Analyze' tools as well as the 'Object Browser' in VS. After that you can inspect the workings of Diagnostics and Process from within C# code in VS. I don't really know what you are asking for, I mean the form of what you are asking for. (i.e., a method that will yield those unnamed methods, parameter names. Or just a way to find them out.)

Comment: @PhonicUK: Ah, I see. I misinterpreted. You might want to look at Roslyn, or NDepend.

Comment: You pretty much just want __Find In Files__ with a RegEx that looks for "(" or ", " before and ", " or ")" after `X`.

Comment: @MarkHurd the parameter name won't appear in my code will it. That'd find any functions with a parameter of that name but that's not what I'm after.

Comment: Yep, I read the OP again and I now understand you want the calls of methods where `X` is a parameter name. That'd need reflection (or a source-equivalent) to enumerate the methods (a relatively straight forward (pseudocode) `for all types, for all methods, where get parameter names contains 'X'`, and then reflector (or source-equivalent) to locate the calls.

Comment: (And now I note the title again and see you clearly stated the request there!)

Comment: @MarkHurd not quite - I only want the ones that I actually *call* anywhere in my code as opposed to all the ones that exist.